# Refused to display Facebook URL in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, sdk

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK in one of the Angular6 application for integrating FB Login. Everything works fine if I am logged into Facebook. But when I am logged out from Facebook, it is showing an error which says `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=######&domain=######&origin=1&redirect_uri=####&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey&version=v3.1  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`. I have checked the oauth URL settings in my Facebook application dashboard and it has my domain it it correctly. How to fix this issue ?

The code I am using is :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(
           (response: any): void => {
               if (response.status === 'connected' && response.authResponse) {
                   FB.api('/me/permissions', (permissions) => {
                       for (let i = 0; i < permissions.data.length; i++) {
                           if (permissions.data[i].status === 'declined' && permissions.data[i].permission === 'email') {
                               emailDeclined = true;
                           }
                       }
                       if (!emailDeclined) {
                           this.userFacebookLogin(response);
                       } else {
                           this.fbLogin('rerequest');
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                 console.log('Not connected');

               }
           },
           true
       );
```

Comment: Who says it needs fixing? Is anything on your site not working because of that? Otherwise, ignore it - it is most likely out of the scope of what you can influence anyway.

Comment: If the status is unknown, I need to show a popup to the user. because of this , I am not able to show it.

Comment: _“because of this , I am not able to show it”_ - please be specific, is this error hindering your further script execution, or is your logic simply not handling what happens in this case correctly? Where exactly does it go wrong?

Comment: I check FB.getLoginStatus() and if it returns `unknown` or `not_authorised` I need to show a popup to the user saying he is not yet connected and he needs to download my app to register. So because of this error it is not able to get back the status from Facebook.If you check the code, you can see console logging . In actual code I have login to show a notification . This is not happening as  I am not able to get the response back from Facebook.

Comment: Is that the only error you get in console? So what happens then, does it not enter your callback function at all?

Comment: yeah. I get only this error and it is not entering into my callback.

Comment: I know this type of error can occur frequently because of the cross-domain voodoo Facebook does in the background, but I have never seen it actually break something. You might have to file a bug report with Facebook then, if it breaks things for you. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Thanks for your time @misorude

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the site url in your app dashboard settings to your development URL. This is the answer that pointed me in the right direction after spending quite some time blocked -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325827/3787212